# What is Wanda drinking?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In the intro scene of *Captain America: Civil War*, we see Wanda pouring something like tea/coffee powder into the cup.

[image: Wanda dipping biscuits]

Then, she stirs it using a spoon:

[image: Wanda stirring tea]

But, when she takes the spoon out, it's dry, implying that there was no liquid in the cup.

[image: Wanda taking dry spoon out]

Though, she is "drinking" something.

[image: Wanda drinking from cup]

So, is this a new kind of 'dry' coffee, or it is an error in the scene?

Comment: It might be the cup was simply empty to make it easier to reset the scene for retakes. Coffee drips on the cup or an already wet spoon are things people, like you :), pick up on.

Comment: She's undercover and on a stakeout. If she actually drinks anything she'll have to use the restroom, which for drama's sake would be the exact time that what she's watching for would happen. Spycraft 101: Food ok, drink not ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It just looks like a sugar packet for her coffee.**

[image: 3 brown sugar packets stacked together with the logo "Sugar in the raw" written on them]

[Here's a common brand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004XG2FIC) in the US that fits the look of the thing.  You can actually see two more of them lined up right next to the other sugar on the right side of your snapshots, right by the Splenda (yellow), and the Sweet'n'Low (pink).  Common arrangement in diners and other likely coffee spots.

So the fact that the spoon is dry is either just a minor production gaffe, or a simple choice.  Sometimes it's just easier to run the scene without needing the actress to consume enough coffee to vibrate through the chair.

Comment: Not like there aren't other brown things that are non-caffeinated that they could have used (decaf, diet cola, tea).  This is definitely a "nobody is going to notice except one guy on a website so why bother" type of thing.

Comment: For the record, a brown packet almost certainly indicates brown sugar.

Comment: @n_b Yes, but they are all liquid.  This would require more bathroom breaks.

Comment: @Mary You don't actually have to drink it, just bring it up to lips.  It could also mess-up make-up (though I assume that _if_ there were liquid in the cup, actress Elizabeth Olsen would be smart enough not to actually drink it).

Answer (score 3):

The film's [official junior novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Marvels-Captain-America-Deluxe-Junior/dp/0316271411) identifies her drink as **coffee**. Presumably it was sufficiently weak that the spoon came out looking largely dry.

> *Wanda Maximoff was dressed in her street clothes, **sipping coffee on
>   the patio of a restaurant in downtown Lagos.** As an Avenger, she was
>   known as Scarlet Witch. She acted casual as she listened to Captain
>   America’s voice through a hidden earpiece. He was watching the area
>   from an upper-floor window in a hotel down the block. “All right, what
>   do you see?”*

As Radhil has pointed out, in the scene she's almost certainly pouring packet sugar into the cup, hence her need to stir it into her coffee